# How to save audio file from flash app to server using php?

Tags: php, flash, audio-recording

My problem is save the audio file (.wav) that my flash application generate when the user finish record your voice.

I use, for this, the follow link: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3/

But this only save the audio for the client. I need to change this for save on the server.

Part of the code is (in MAIN.AS):

```
private function recordComplete(e:Event):void{
    fileReference.save(recorder.output, "recording.wav");
}
```

Where the first argument (recorder.output) is my file and the second argument is the name of my file.

I change this method for this:

```
private function recordComplete(e:Event):void{
  var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("extract_voice.php");
  urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  urlReq.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
  //var urlVars = new URLVariables();
  //urlVars.fileAudio = recorder.output;
  urlReq.data = recorder.output;
  //var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlReq);
  //loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
  loader.load(urlReq);
}
```

And my extract_voice.php is:

```
$recorder = file_get_contents('php://input');
$name = basename($recorder);
$status = move_uploaded_file($recorder, 'http://localhost/recording/audiofiles/' . $name);
if($status){
  echo 'WORK';
}
```

But when stop the recording, always show me the popup for save the file on my machine. (client).But not in the server.

Anyone can say me what I need to do? or if exist any other solution? (Like a RED5 but this doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $recorder = file_get_contents('php://input');

`$recorder` variable holds binary data fetched from php input, not uploaded file. Instead of

```
$name = basename($recorder);
$status = move_uploaded_file($recorder, 'http://localhost/recording/audiofiles/' . $name);
```

use:

```
$name = md5($recorder).'.wav';
$status = file_put_contents('recording/audiofiles/'.$name, $recorder);
```

Note, that path to the file must be writable to web server, and it must be local path, not some web address.

Comment: I'm doing print_r for the variable $recorder and is empty.

Comment: I really think that the follow code: $recorder = file_get_contents('php://input');
Don't work, or in the MAIN.AS don't send the file wav to my php script.